# how to verify phone number which is already there in database or not, and have to send otp only to register mobile numbers

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing Android application where the application should display registred profile after verifying the user mobile number using OTP. I am using MySQL as database and accessing the database using PHP and parsing the reply from PHP using JSON. I am using REST service for developing this application. Can you help me out to find the solution?
i have to send otp for only registred phone numbers
thanks in advance

Comment: please provide a piece of your code where you facing the issue with some tries to fixing it

Comment: Please study tutorial. write mysql query in your php page. First select table and using where condition - this used to find out particular mobile number is in your db or not..

Comment: yes,, i wrote mysql query in php page......i need android code to check whether num is der or ot

Comment: please share your code. that's better to get the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937310/connecting-php-with-android-check-if-value-exists-in-mysql-database pls check this link

Answer (score 0):

Get the registered phone number from PHP, send OTP via PHP only. The user will verify mobile number via API hit and check if OTP matches the user's phone number and set a field for verified number as yes/no or 0/1. Then while sending response via PHP check if mobile number is verified or not. Handling request and response at PHP end is the better way as it will require less changes in the app.

**PHP CODE GENERATE OTP**

```
public function generaterefCode() {
        $alphabet = "0123456789";
        $pass = array();
        $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
            $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
            $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
            }
        return implode($pass);

    }
```

This function will generate OTP. Get this OTP, send sms to registered mobile number and save it in DB against the mobile number.

Get a request from Android APP with user Id, mobile number, and OTP sent.
Then fetch values from db for the user id and check if mobile number and OTP matches. After this update the db as mobile verified yes/no or 0/1

Comment: sir , can u plz share php code to generate otp n verify mobile number

Answer (score 0):

```
if($this->isNumAlreadyExists(9XXXXXXXX1)){
 $query = 'INSERT INTO OTP_table VALUES (9XXXXXXXX1, OTP, USERID)';
 (new PDO())->query($query);
 $code = rand(10, 99) . rand(10, 99) . rand(10, 99);
 $status = $this->sendSMS(9XXXXXXXX1, $code);
}

function sendSMS($number, $code){
 //user curl call of your sms service provider   
}

function isNumAlreadyExists($number){
  $query = 'SELECT UserID FROM table_user WHERE Mobile = 9XXXXXXXX1';
  $tmp = (new PDO())->query($query);
  $result = $tmp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if($result){
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the table's OTP field NULL (by default). When the OTP is generated the the null value have to be replaced with generated OTP value. 
After the verification process from the user side. write a query to make the field NULL again.